# Android iBeacon library no longer available

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

Now that Radius Networks' Android iBeacon library is no longer available, can we still use it for commercial purposes? Many of us still have a fork of the code.

Relevant links: https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/android-ibeacon-service

Takedown message: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:JhROX9F_DMsJ:developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/07/14/a-note-from-the-ceo.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au

Comment: I notice that they have [Proximity Kit Android Library](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/proximitykit/). They say it is the same as the Android Pro Library and built upon Android iBeacon Library. Probably that's the most legal way, although I can't confirm whether it has same functions or not.

Comment: The Proximity Kit is simply an SDK which sits on top of their android library which they no longer support (it was available before the takedown). Not sure if support for the android version of the proximity kit would stay up (it wouldn't make much sense?) since it quite literally has a JAR file of the library inside the kit...

Answer (score 0):

The software was released under an Apache license, so you have rights under those terms, which includes embedding it in your programs and redistributing the source.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in their webpage, it's replaced by [Android Beacon Library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library) which is well maintained. To use it for iBeacon:

```
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
```